# check for required arguments in array

Tags: php

How can I easiest (fastest) check that an array contains N specific elements in PHP.

Similar to

```
array_key_exists($key, array $array)
```

but rather

```
array_keys_exists(array $requiredKeys, array $array)
```

Comment: Do all `$requiredKeys` need to exist or only one?

Comment: @PeeHaal. All. BTW. I can code it, but I'm looking for some C-wise shortcut here...

Comment: I have no idea what "C-wise" shortcut means, but what's the issue with a `foreach` and `in_array`?

Comment: @PeeHaa, nothing wrong with foreach, but I'd like a one-liner...

Answer (score 2):

you can use `array_intersect_key(array $requiredKeys, array $array);`

it will return an array with the matching keys, then you can compare the length of your required keys array and the one returned by the function to check if all exists

```
<?php

//The values in this arrays contains the names of the indexes (keys)
// that should exist in the data array
$required = array('key1', 'key2', 'key3' );

$data = array(
    'key1' => 10,
    'key2' => 20,
    'key3' => 30,
    'key4' => 40
);

if(count(array_intersect_key(array_flip($required), $data)) === count($required)) {
    //All required keys exist!              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$required = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
if (array_diff_key(array_flip($required), $array)) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Required keys: %s, got: %s',
                                join(', ', $required),
                                join(', ', array_keys($array))));
}
```

If [`array_diff_key`](http://php.net/array_diff_key) returns anything but an empty array (`== false`), that means some keys are missing. You can even store that difference and tell the user/developer exactly which keys are missing in the error message if you were so inclined.